# Measure of noncompactness estimate

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, compactness

I am trying to understand a proof, but there is one estimate i really don't understand.
Let $E$ be a Banach space, $x_n:[0,b]\rightarrow E$ differentiable. Then we have for the Kuratowski measure of noncompactness $\alpha$, a fixed $t\in[0,b]$, and for all $\tau\leq t$
$$\alpha\left(\left\{\frac{x_n(t)-x_n(t-h)}{h}:n\geq k,0<h\leq \tau\right\}\right)\leq \alpha\left(\bigcup_{s\in[t-\tau,t]}\{x_n'(s):n\geq k\}\right)$$

The paper just says that, you proof it with a kind of the mean value theorem and the property $\alpha(\mathrm{conv}(X))=\alpha(X)$. Nevertheless i really don't know, how the author gets this estimate.
Is it possible, that it is even wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality seems correct to me. The mean value theorem used here is the following:

Let $f:[a,b] \to E$ be differentiable. Then
$$
\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} \in \overline{\rm conv} \{f'(s):s \in [a,b]\}.
$$

Now fix $k \in \mathbb{N}$, $0<\tau \le b$ and $t \in [\tau,b]$. Then for all $0 < h \le \tau$ and all $m \ge k$
$$
\frac{x_m(t)-x_m(t-h)}{h} \in \overline{\rm conv} \{x_m'(s):s \in [t-h,t]\}
$$
$$
\subseteq \overline{\rm conv} \{x_n'(s):s \in [t-\tau,t], n \ge k\}.
$$
Thus
$$
\{\frac{x_n(t)-x_n(t-h)}{h} :n \ge k, 0< h \le \tau\} \subseteq
\overline{\rm conv} \{x_n'(s):s \in [t-\tau,t], n \ge k\}
$$
and the inequality follows form the properties of Kuratowski measure of noncompactness. A proof of the mean value theorem above can be found in
the book of Martin R.H.: Nonlinear Operators and Differential Equations in Banach Spaces, Wiley (1976), Theorem 2.1